# Remap CMD+H shortcut in OSX

Tags: regex, macos, keyboard-shortcuts

Is it possible to remap the "Hide Window" shortcut in OSX? I know about the possibility to remap just about any shortcut in the System Preferences that are either built in or just available in a specific app.

The thing is that CMD+H is not being shown as a 'built-in' shortcut. Also this shortcut is special in that it has a different name in the menu in every app in that it is called "Hide Appname". That makes it impossible to generically add it manually to the shortcuts. Unless there was a way to use Regexps or there would be a magic constant like "Appname".

---

The reason I'm asking this silly question is that I want to use CMD inside my Linux VMs as Meta key so that my tiling window manager has a sweet shortcut. Currently this works fine, unless I accidentally hide the Window(:

Comment: The system preferences method should work if you set it for the application...

Comment: @l'L'l How should it be set for the application? Every application has a different name - hence the Menu Item has a different name every time. I might not have made myself clear enough in the description. If I were to hide Firefox, the Menu Item would be "Hide Firefox", in Terminal it would be "Hide Terminal". It seems unreasonable that I should have to create shortcuts manually for every installed application on my system. That does not scale well(;